# Inverse Laplace transform of a rational function

Tags: laplace-transform

Could you please help me the following Inverse Laplace problem

$$\frac{2s^2+4s+3}{s(s^2+s+0.5)}$$

$F(t)$ is required.

Comment: You can use partial fractions to split off $s$ in the denominator from the $s^2+s+0.5$. Then, you can complete the square on $s^2+s+0.5$, getting it into the form $(s-a)^2+b^2$ or $(s-a)^2 - b^2$. (Probably the first one.) Then, look up the tables.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First use partial fraction to get

> $$ \frac{6}{s} - \frac{2}{\left( s+1/2+i/2 \right)}-\frac{2}{\left( s+1/2-i/2 \right)}\quad i=\sqrt{-1}$$

then you can use the [tables](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf).